# When to use -ni ikimasuka or -masuka

Tags: particle-に

Do these both mean exactly the same thing?

> 何時に子どもを迎えますか
> 何時に子どもを迎えに行きますか

“When do you pick up your child?”

I suppose the second says “when do you leave to pick up your child” more precisely?

If so, is that the difference between the two? I don’t know which form to use in general conversation and what sounds less or more “wooden”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb 迎える alone can mean to go greet someone, but the meaning is closer to "welcome" or even "herald". So, if you say 子供を迎える, it actually means to "welcome a child into your life".

For the more everyday occurrence like picking up your child, it's more natural to say "子供を迎えに行く".

Comment: Thanks, although I do not know yet what -ku means here. I need to learn this grammar still.

Comment: Still, is it correct to assume -ni ikimasu is generally preferred and more natural than using the verb immediately, when it involves a certain action?

Comment: -ku is just the base form (the stem) for the verb 行く（いく） from which you can conjugate the polite form 行きます（いきます）.

Comment: It depends on the verb you are using and the context of the sentence. -ni ikimasu is not always necessary or natural. However, you can understand adding "-ni ikimasu" as meaning "leaving to ______" or "going to _____".